# How to adjust SQL LIKE function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching, sql-like

I want to make this kind of query:

```
create procedure something
  @name varchar(13)
as
begin

  select * 
   from WORKER
  where NAME LIKE "%@name%"

end
```

For input `@name=ho`, I want output every row that contains NAME which sounds `ho`,

for example HOuse, soHO, broHOw...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Select * from WORKER where Name Like '%' + @name + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create procedure something
@name varchar(13)
as
begin
select * from WORKER
where NAME LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
end
```